# Windows 10 Task Manager overestimates network usage approx. tenfold

Tags: windows-10

For an unknown reason the task manager in Windows 10 is overestimating networking usage. As you can see here it's off by almost tenfold.

[image]

I had a look at this [related answer](https://superuser.com/questions/626073/how-to-make-windows-task-manager-to-show-network-usage) where the task manager was showing no network usage at all and disabled **Virtualbox Bridged Networking Driver** with no difference.

Comment: They are not the same unit.  perform the conversion you will find that task manager is indeed reporting the correct speed.  Keep in mind what you see is the total network usage of the process, and what is being reported on the other side, is the speed of the download of that specific file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the unit difference.

One is MegaBytes and the other is MegaBits, so it should be off by a factor of 8.  So 48.1 megabits/sec equals ~6.

You can use the [Google converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+mib+to+megabytes) to help with this.

For more info, perhaps check out this related SU question: [Converting bandwidth: Bps-Bytes/s MBit-MB](https://superuser.com/questions/301015/converting-bandwidth-bps-bytes-s-mbit-mb)

So that accounts for the big difference. However, they are also measuring different things.

The application is counting the number of bytes it has received, which will be less than the aggregate of the system, which includes control packets, resends, plus whatever other applications/system are sending & receiving.